# Need help fixing MBR on 2K3/Vista multiboot Dell 620

Tags: windows-vista, multi-boot, windows-server-2003, mbr

Such a long story and pain in the butt... My customer has asked me to load 7 windows vista clients and 4 windows server 2K3 machines bare metal(because apparently VM's aren't good enough) on a Dell 620 with 4 hard disks(500GB ea.). After much trial getting the drivers right and other problems I have had success getting all 11 images onto the box. However, now if 2K3 is that last OS to get installed then I can change the boot.ini file and boot into all of the 2K3 images fine, but not vista because vista uses boot manager. If I load vista as the last OS then I can run do bcdedit to recognize all of the other vista OS's and even the 2K3 OS's but the 2K3 can't be loaded because the NTLDR is not found, because vista trashed it. I have both disks... but the vista disk is not exactly oem, don't ask. It is licensed but comes from a third party distributor who locked it down like no other(I assume for security reasons), so I can use it to install new images but it doesn't give me a repair option. I would be eternally grateful if someone who has experience multibooting windows old and new could tell me what to do next. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as that:

All boot files MUST be on active partition first disk.
ntldr, boot.ini, ntdetect.com, bootmgr, \boot folder with BCD.

In boot.ini you specify old NT5 systems.
In BCD you specify all systems.

You can use [ARCPaths utility](http://www.boyans.net/ArcPaths/ArcPaths.htm) for exact ARC Paths for all drives.

Try [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) - it can create all loaders on one go. (backup BCD and boot.ini !!!)

Try [Dual-boot Repair tool newest version](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-tool-for-windows-8.1-update.html) (should fix boot sectors and MBR, ntldr, bootmgr, BCD).

Read tools manuals (one web page each), eventually help files.

Feedback would be nice.

Comment: Thank you for the response! VisualBCD worked great and fixed all of the Vista images in bootmgr. It also recognized and added entries for the 2K3 images, but i was still unable to boot into them. When I tried I got "NTLDR not found". So I did some more research and eventually downloaded ntldr & ntdetect.com files on a floppy along with the correct boot.ini file. Then I booted into the repair environment via the 2K3 install disk and copied the 3 files to each 2K3 partition. That fixed the problem, I can now boot into all Vista and 2K3 images. Thanks again!

Comment: Good for you that you fixed your problem. Did you use NEWEST Dual-boot Repair tool (for Win 8.1) (it should have fixed "NTLDR not found") ?